# converting mysql binlogs to text format without using mysqlbinlog tool

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I need to convert the mysql binlogs to text format in PHP script. I am aware of using `mysqlbinlog` tool to convert it to text. But I am not supposed to run any system commands(or any shell command) in my script.

Is there any other way to do it using PHP?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "Not supposed to use any system commands"? What is that supposed to mean? What about doing it without computers? That's equally absurd. Use the right tool for the job, and if that's `mysqlbinlog`, then use that.

Comment: ok, updated the question now, What I meant was I cannot run any commands in my php script. So is there any other method to convert it in php? @tadman

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-log-versions.html Describes the internal format of a binlog file

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: This seems like a very risky undertaking. Why can't you run any commands?

Comment: you can look for any binlog reader php library and use that.